# Sparklyr connection to YARN cluster fails

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ambari, sparklyr

I am trying to connect to a **Spark cluster** using `sparklyr` on yarn-client mode.
On local mode (`master = "local"`) my spark setup works, but when I try to connect to the **Cluster**, I get the following error

```
Error in force(code) :
    Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
```

(see full error log below)

The setup is as follows. The **spark cluster** (hosted on **AWS**), setup with **Ambari**, runs on **yarn 3.1.1**, **spark 2.3.2**, **hdfs 3.1.1**, and some other services and works with other platforms (i.e., non R/Python applications setup with **Ambari**. Note that a setup using **Ambari** is not possible, as the R machine runs on **Ubuntu**, and the **Spark cluster** on **CentOS 7**).

On my R machine I use the following code. Note that I have installed `java 8-openjdk` and the correct spark version.

Inside of my `YARN_CONF_DIR` I have created the `yarn-site.xml` file, as exported from **Ambari** (Services -> Download All Client Configs). I have also tried to copy the files `hdfs-site.xml` and `hive-site.xml` with the same result.

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(DBI)

# spark_install("2.3.2")
spark_installed_versions()
#>   spark hadoop                                         dir
#> 1 2.3.2    2.7 /home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7

# use java 8 instead of java 11 (not supported with Spark 2.3.2 only 3.0.0+)
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/")
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR = "/home/david/Spark-test/yarn-conf")

conf <- spark_config()

conf$spark.executor.memory <- "500M"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 2
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 1
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = conf)
#> Error in force(code) :
#>     Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig 
#> ...
```

I am not really sure how to debug this, on which machine the error originates, or how to fix it, thus any help and or hint is greatly appreciated!

## Edit / Progress

So far I have found out, that the spark version installed by sparklyr (from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.3.2/)), depends on [glassfish](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/), whereas my cluster depends on an oracle java installation (hence the `com/sun/...` path).

This applies to the following java packages:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
ll <- list.files("~/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/", pattern = "^jersey", full.names = TRUE)

df <- map_dfr(ll, function(f) {
  x <- system(glue("jar tvf {f}"), intern = TRUE)
  tibble(file = f, class = str_extract(x, "[^ ]+$"))
})

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(class, "com/sun")) %>% 
  count(file)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   file                                                                           n
#>   <chr>                                                                      <int>
#> 1 /home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars//activation-1.1.1.jar        15
#> 2 /home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars//derby.log                 1194
#> 3 /home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars//jersey-client-1.19.jar     108
#> 4 /home/david/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars//jersey-server-2.22.2.jar    22
```

I have tried to load the latest jar files from maven (e.g., from [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.19.4)) for the files `jersey-client.jar` and `jersey-core.jar` and now the connection takes ages and does not finish (at least not the same error anymore, Yay I guess...). Any idea what the cause of this issue is?

### Full Error log

```
Error in force(code) : 
  Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:136)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:61)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler$$anonfun$channelRead0$1.apply$mcV$sp(handler.scala:58)
    at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:38)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:38)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 49 more

    Log: /tmp/RtmpIKnflg/filee462cec58ee_spark.log


---- Output Log ----
20/07/16 10:20:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Session (3779) is starting under 127.0.0.1 port 8880
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Session (3779) found port 8880 is not available
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) found port 8884 is available
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is registering session in gateway
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is waiting for registration in gateway
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) finished registration in gateway with status 0
20/07/16 10:20:42 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8884
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) accepted connection
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8884
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) received command 0
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) found requested session matches current session
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is creating backend and allocating system resources
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is using port 8885 for backend channel
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) created the backend
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO sparklyr: Backend (3779) is waiting for r process to end
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.3.2
20/07/16 10:20:43 WARN SparkConf: spark.master yarn-client is deprecated in Spark 2.0+, please instead use "yarn" with specified deploy mode.
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: sparklyr
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42419.
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/07/16 10:20:43 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-583db378-821a-4990-bfd2-5fcaf95d071b
20/07/16 10:20:44 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/07/16 10:20:44 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/07/16 10:20:44 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
20/07/16 10:20:44 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
20/07/16 10:20:44 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://{SPARK IP}
```

Then in the `/tmp/RtmpIKnflg/filee462cec58ee_spark.log` file

```
20/07/16 10:09:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Session (11296) is starting under 127.0.0.1 port 8880
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Session (11296) found port 8880 is not available
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) found port 8882 is available
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is registering session in gateway
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is waiting for registration in gateway
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) finished registration in gateway with status 0
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8882
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) accepted connection
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8882
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) received command 0
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) found requested session matches current session
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is creating backend and allocating system resources
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is using port 8883 for backend channel
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) created the backend
20/07/16 10:09:07 INFO sparklyr: Backend (11296) is waiting for r process to end
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.3.2
20/07/16 10:09:08 WARN SparkConf: spark.master yarn-client is deprecated in Spark 2.0+, please instead use "yarn" with specified deploy mode.
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: sparklyr
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: david
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: david
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(david); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(david); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 44541.
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-d7b67ab2-508c-4488-ac1b-7ee0e787aa79
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://{THE INTERNAL SPARK IP}:4040
20/07/16 10:09:08 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/david/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.3-2.11.jar at spark://{THE INTERNAL SPARK IP}:44541/jars/sparklyr-2.3-2.11.jar with timestamp 1594894148685
20/07/16 10:09:09 ERROR sparklyr: Backend (11296) failed calling getOrCreate on 11: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:136)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:61)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler$$anonfun$channelRead0$1.apply$mcV$sp(handler.scala:58)
    at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:38)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:38)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 49 more
```